# Strange Results of Using Transparent Color

Tags: java, swing

While testing the following simple code I see a strange behavior: the button which has a transparent background color, gets more and more opaque, while the mouse enters or exits out of the bounds of the button. What is this strange behavior for? The code is as follows:

```
public class TransparentColorTest
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
        frame.setSize( 200 , 200 );
        Color transparentColor = new Color( 0 , 0 , 255 , 20 );
        JButton testButton = new JButton();
        testButton.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 100 , 100 ) );
        testButton.setBackground( transparentColor );
        frame.add( testButton );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

The fourth argument to the Color constructor, determines the transparency of the color.

Comment: That doesn't happen on Mac O/SX with Java 1.8.0_66.  What are you running?

Comment: I'm using windows 10, with java 1.8.0_102.

Comment: Swing only knows how to paint opaque and non-opaque components, it doens't know how paint components with alpha based colors, instead, you need to fake it, [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201634/how-contents-are-made-translucent-in-a-jpanel/14206130#14206130

Comment: See [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for an explanation of the problem and a simple solution.